# How to swap or reverse day and month of date in openoffice?

Tags: openoffice

I have over 3000 rows of numbers that i need to sort by days. but its reading the days wrong.

if i do: Format Cells.. -> Numbers -> Format code -> D.MMM.YY

12/01/15    ->  D.MMM.YY   ->  1.Jan.15  (it needs to be 12.Jan.15)
20/09/16    ->  D.MMM.YY   ->  20.sep.16

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I swap or reverse day and month?

1. Highlight the column with the Date Value.
2. Menu > "Data" > "Text to Columns".
3. In the Dialog Box, select the column.
4. In "Column Type" select "Date (DMY).

   [image]
5. Click OK.
6. Menu > "Format" > "Cells".
7. Select the "Numbers" tab.
8. In "Category" select "Date.
9. In "Format code" enter "D.MMM.YY"

   [image]
10. Click "OK"

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]